# Configure a CronString for a BiWeekly job in Quartz.Net

Tags: quartz.net, cronexpression

How can I configure a CronString for Quartz.Net job scheduler for the following job:

Job should run on BiWeekly on Monday at 12:00 AM. i.e. it should run on every Monday but skipping one week in between.

Example:

```
1st Run => 19-Nov-2012 [Monday] 12:00 AM
2nd Run => 03-Dec-2012 [Monday] 12:00 AM
3rd Run => 17-Dec-2012 [Monday] 12:00 AM
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually what you might be looking for is CalenderIntervalTrigger, which is capable to do this easily.

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .StartAt(new DateTime(2012, 11, 19, 12, 0, 0).ToUniversalTime())
    .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInWeeks(2))
    .Build();
```

Comment: Ok...cause we are Great. But can't we do the same using a cron string? Because currently in my app we are scheduling all jobs using cron string only.

Comment: Unfortunately no. You could do some evil trickery inside job to detect is this every other week when running every week but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

A "cron expresssion" can be created as follows for any frequency of the week.

```
int repeatInterval = 2;
int weeklyInterval = repeatInterval*7;
String cronExp="0 0 12 1/ " +weeklyInterval " * ? *";
```

Creates a cron expression which repeats bi-weekly at 12.

Hope this helps.