# How can I create a cron schedule that repeats every 2 weeks on Mondays?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, cronexpression

I need to create a cron schedule that repeats every 2 weeks on Mondays. Cronmaker.com doesn't have the cron expression for this. Please advice.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen a single CRON expression that can do this, but since you're using Quartz, a similar question was answered that achieves this programmatically.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13611082/2707705

Comment: Please remember to vote if this answers your question.

Comment: var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .StartAt(new DateTime(2012, 11, 19, 12, 0, 0).ToUniversalTime())
    .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInWeeks(2))
    .Build();

How can I specify its on a monday?

Comment: By choosing a date that starts on a Monday.  Naturally, every following 14 days will also be on a Monday.

Answer (score 2):

for cron expressions i use cronmaker.com and generate them there.  There's also a jquery plugin (https://github.com/shawnchin/jquery-cron) if you want to roll your own.