# Quartz: Weekly cron expression

Tags: java, cron, expression

I cannot find a working cron expression for:

- Run every X weeks (case "semaine")

Do not forget to take into account the start date !

```
private static String generateCronExpression(Date startTime, String periodicity, long value) throws Exception {
    String second = new SimpleDateFormat("s").format(startTime);
    String minute = new SimpleDateFormat("m").format(startTime);
    String hour = new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(startTime);
    String day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(startTime);
    String month = new SimpleDateFormat("M").format(startTime);

    switch (periodicity) {
    case "seconde":
        return second + "/" + value + " * * 1/1 * ? *";
    case "minute":
        return second + " 0/" + value + " * 1/1 * ? *";
    case "heure":
        return second + " " + minute + " 0/" + value + " 1/1 * ? *";
    case "jour":
        return second + " " + minute + " " + hour + " " + day + "/" + value + " * ? *";
    case "semaine":
        return second + " " + minute + " " + hour + " " + day + "/" + (7 * value) + " * ? *";
    case "mois":
        return second + " " + minute + " " + hour + " " + day + " 1/" + value + " ? *";
    case "annee":
        return second + " " + minute + " " + hour + " " + day + " " + month + " ? " + "0/" + value;
    default:
        throw new Exception("[generateCronExpression] - Unknown periodicity");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want us to do, except observing this poorly written code?

Comment: I use Quartz and I want to run a job every X seconds or every X weeks.
I just want to use Cron expressions.
All expressions works except 2

Comment: Did you read official Quartz documentation? It is quite clear and detailed.

Comment: Yes or I would not be here....................................................

Comment: If you are here just to criticize, just go thank you.
Why my code is poorly written?

Comment: I don't think weekly take a number of days, but the day it should be run on. I formatted and condensed your code here: http://pastebin.com/8CgC0aza This is easier to read. Also, there is a tool called http://www.cronmaker.com/ which actually uses Quartz.

Comment: Yes thank you I'll use your method, it's easier to read.
I just did my expressions cronmaker but for the last expression I block.

Comment: "last expression I block" ? Can you elaborate?

Comment: if you want to trigger the job you can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13611082/1982680